# How to remove perlbrew versions/installations?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I'm running perl-5.32.0 on an Ubuntu VM, and I keep getting this warning every time I open a new terminal:

`ERROR: The installation "perl-5.30.0" is unknown.`

I removed directories to old versions, which caused this error (disk space is at a premium).

I don't see a command within the perlbrew menu that can remove a version.  I've run `perlbrew clean` which cleaned up a lot of disk space, but I still get the error.

I've thought about editing the header file

```
con@V:~/.perlbrew$ cat init 
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
export PERLBREW_MANPATH="/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/man"
export PERLBREW_PATH="/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/con/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/bin"
export PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.30.0"
export PERLBREW_ROOT="/home/con/perl5/perlbrew"
export PERLBREW_VERSION="0.86"
```

but given `# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE` I don't think I should do that.

How can I get rid of the error `ERROR: The installation "perl-5.30.0" is unknown.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is due to `perlbrew` trying to use a non-existent installation. The solution isn't removing a perlbrew-installed Perl;<sup>[1]</sup> the solution it simply to tell it to start using an existing one.

To get the list of perlbrew-managed builds and switch to an existing one:

```sh
perlbrew list
perlbrew switch {id}
```

To turn off perlbrew (e.g. if you have no perlbrew-managed installations left):

```sh
perlbrew switch-off
```

It can be reinstated using `perlbrew switch`.

---

1. To answer the title question, even though it you won't help you personally here, you can use the following to uninstall a perlbrew-managed build of Perl:

   ```sh
   perlbrew uninstall {id}
   ```

Answer (score 2):

To [uninstall](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-perlbrew/script/perlbrew#COMMAND:-UNINSTALL) a perl version within `perlbrew` use:

```
perlbrew uninstall <name>
```

The `<name>` is one from `perlbrew list`.

Comment: That doesn't help. `'perl-5.30.0' is not installed`